# create kafka consumer with protobuf

Tags: java, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I want to write a kafka consumer using protobuf format as the message is in proto format, I have tried this [link](https://github.com/zuowang/kafka-protobuf) but not helpful , can anybody suggest anything.

Comment: What exactly from that link did you try? What errors are you getting? What difficulty are you having taking a byte array to a Protobuf object?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the following link,

https://github.com/daniccan/HttpToKafkaProcessor

This project contains a Kafka Producer that pushes a protobuf object into Kafka. You can use this as an reference to write your own Kafka Consumer.